# Using custom rtl.css style downloaded with theme in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, right-to-left

I have downloaded Wordpress theme and it has a rtl.css file in it's files how can i activate it i cant find `<link ....../>` in header or any available clear option or tool to use it .how can i use this rtl.css file?

Answer (score 0):

The `rtl.css` file is activated if the language used in your settings is an RTL language.

Go to Settings -> General Settings -> Site Language (at the bottom) and choose an RTL language like Arabic, Farsi or Hebrew; your rtl.css file is then used automatically.

If you want to use it in any other configuration, you will have to add it manually, either by creating a child theme, or by using `wp_enqueue_style` in your `functions.php`. See [WordPress' RTL support](https://codex.wordpress.org/Right-to-Left_Language_Support) for more information.